# Add a specific node module in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bulma

I have added one of Bulma extensions in my react project 
https://wikiki.github.io/components/quickview/

To use it I have installed it using npm & extension requires to add below line when DOM is completely loaded, so I added it in componentDidMount

```
var quickviews = bulmaQuickview.attach();
```

and below line in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-quickview/dist/js/bulma-quickview.min.js"></script>
```

I am using webpack to bundle & have excluded all node modules from bundle.

**Problem :**  In development environment for webpack it works fine but after bundling for production it gives me error that

> bulmaQuickview is not defined

How can I bundle a specific node module in my webpack bundle? and what will be the correct reference to add.

Webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }]

            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/image'),
                loader: 'file-loader'

            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new WebpackNotifierPlugin(), new BrowserSyncPlugin(), new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'API_URL': API_URL[environment]
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Provide your `webpack.config` code. This is not enough to know what the issue is.

Comment: @HemantParashar added webpack config

Answer (score 0):

You're adding it to the index.html so webpack isn't bundling it. Have you tried importing it into the same js file that it is used in? Either that or add it to your entry property after index.html ([make it an array](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)).

Comment: I had tried importing it and even used `require` but didn't help.will try the multiple entry approach

Comment: It's strange because the documentation doesn't give a lot of options! If the above doesn't work then you could use webpack's htmlWebpackPlugin to generate the index.html. you can pass a template file as an option which is where you can add your script tag. [This article]( https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/index-html-using-html-webpack-plugin-85eabdb73474) shows you how.

Comment: for now, I have added the required js file in my output `dist` folder directly from node modules & have referenced that in index.html and it works. But will check both of your options.

Comment: I don't know what you production build will look like but bear in mind that you will unlikely have the node_modules folder in production, it's the job of webpack to bundle all of your dependencies together so these options  may not work in the real world. Good luck